# How to return value from inner $http-function in outer function in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using an Angular service as an interface for API calls. In this case JavaScript's asynchronous nature makes this difficult. Do you have any suggestions to how I should do it?

```
function getOrder(orderId) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '<api-url> + orderId'
    }).success(function (result) {
        /* --- getOrder should return parameter 'result' --- */
    });
}
```

Comment: convert it into `promise pattern` using `.then` function..do return data from it.and then the consumer method's `.then` will get called.

Answer (score 1):

Better return the promise:

```js
function getOrder(orderId) {
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '<api-url>' + orderId
  });
}
```

Then, when calling:

```js
getOrder("1").then(function(response) {
  // response.data contains the returned data
});
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage

---

Please note the [deprecation notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice) about `success` and `error`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with callback functions and promises? I think you should have an additional parameter in you getOrder function, the callback function, which you should call with the results or the error message with.

Here is an introduction for this:
http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

or just return the promise itself, as mentioned above!